# UTF 8 Special Characters when converting JString to String in JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to convert a String to a JString in JNI, but when the string contains UTF 8 special characters, it doesn't seems to be saving in the right way.

For example: “Avda. Espaᡬ 1” when it should be “Avda. España 1”.

This is my code:

```
jstr= env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());
```

Is there a way to convert to JString specifying the UTF 8 charset?

Comment: `NewStringUTF()` accepts "modified" UTF-8 strings (the two modifications being the encoding of embedded nulls and handling of surrogate pairs). You should generate a hex dump of your source string to confirm that the encoding is UTF-8 and not CP1252.

Comment: You should update the title to "... when converting std::string to jstring, and provide more information and/or source code showing the problem

Answer (score 2):

I copied these from somewhere, added exception handling. they work in production.

```
// jstring to std::wstring
std::wstring jstr2wsz(JNIEnv *env, jstring string)
{
    std::wstring wStr;
    if (string == NULL) 
    {
        return wStr; // empty string
    }

    try
    {
        const jchar *raw = env->GetStringChars(string, NULL);
        if (raw != NULL)
        {
            jsize len = env->GetStringLength(string);
            wStr.assign(raw, raw + len);
            env->ReleaseStringChars(string, raw);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception ex)
    {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION in jstr2wsz translating string input " << string << std::endl;
        std::cout << "exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return wStr;
}

// std::wstring to jstring
jstring wsz2jstr(JNIEnv *env, std::wstring cstr)
{
    jstring result = nullptr;
    try
    {
        int len = cstr.size();
        jchar* raw = new jchar[len];
        memcpy(raw, cstr.c_str(), len * sizeof(wchar_t));
        result = env->NewString(raw, len);
        delete[] raw;
        return result;
    }
    catch (const std::exception ex)
    {
        std::wcout << L"EXCEPTION in wsz2jstr translating string input " <<     cstr << std::endl;
        std::cout << "exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

return result;
```

}